# Append a specific column of one file into another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have N separate tab files with 3 columns each. The first two columns are identical for each file. For example (N=3 files):

`file1.tsv`:

```
A1    B1    1
A2    B2    9
A3    B3    8
```

`file2.tsv`:

```
A1    B1    5
A2    B2    8
A3    B3    4
```

`file3.tsv`:

```
A1    B1    0
A2    B2    1
A3    B3    7
```

I would like to create a new file by appending the third column of each file to the first file. Basically I would like this:

`output.tsv`:

```
A1    B1    1    5    0
A2    B2    9    8    1
A3    B3    8    4    7
```

I could potentially have many files so I'm interested in a solution that uses a loop or that can fit an unfixed number of files.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've attempted and the (wrong) output generated by your code; also of interest ... some idea on max number of files and max size of files (might come in handy when taking into consideration whether or not a solution can be done in memory or if intermediate files will need to be used)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command for above purpose

```
#!/bin/bash
list=file2.txt,file3.txt
cp file1.txt output.txt 

for file in $(echo ${list} | tr "," " "); do
        cut -f3 "$file" | paste output.txt - > temp.txt
        mv temp.txt output.txt
done
```

Here both cut and paste commands use tab as delimiter by default. so the `output.txt` file will have the result as tab delimeter.

Comment: This would fail, if one of the file names contained a comma or a space. It would make more sense to make `list` an array of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is another option. You can simply read the first file first, store the contents in an array, then read each subsequent file (in the order specified as input) and append a `tab` and the last column from each to the lines in your array, then using the `END` rule, output your array.

For example you can do:

```bash
awk -F"\t" '
  NR == FNR { a[++n] = $0; next}                    # save 1st file in a[]
  { i++; a[i] = a[i] "\t" $NF; if (i == n) i = 0 }  # append last column
  END { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i] }           # output a[]
' file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data *tab-separated* (presuming from the `.tsv` extension) in `file1.tsv`, `file2.tsv` and `file3.tsv`, you can simply paste the solution above at the command-line in the directory containing the files and receive:

```
$  awk -F"\t" '
>   NR == FNR { a[++n] = $0; next}                    # save 1st file in a[]
>   { i++; a[i] = a[i] "\t" $NF; if (i == n) i = 0 }  # append last column
>   END { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i] }           # output a[]
> ' file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv
A1      B1      1       5       0
A2      B2      9       8       1
A3      B3      8       4       7
```

You can redirect to a new file just by adding  `> newfile.tsv`.

**Creating an awk Script**

You can place the `awk` commands in an awk-script file and execute it just like you would any other script. For example you can rewrite the above in the script file name `append_last.awk` and make it executable with `chmod +x append_last.awk`. You can move setting the field-separator `FS` into the `BEGIN` rule and expand the comments as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/awk -f

# BEGIN rule
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }       # set tab a field-separator

# first rule
NR == FNR {               # if first file
  a[++n] = $0             # store records in indexed array a[]
  next
}

# second rule
{
  i++                     # increment counter
  a[i] = a[i] "\t" $NF    # append tab and last column to a[i]
  if (i == n)             # test if i equals last line in file
    i = 0                 #   reset to 0
}

# END rule
END {
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)    # loop over each array element
    print a[i]            # outputting element
}
```

Now you run it just like any other script providing the input files as arguments, e.g.

```
$ ./append_last.awk file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv
A1      B1      1       5       0
A2      B2      9       8       1
A3      B3      8       4       7
```

To redirect to a new file, as above, just add your redirection, e.g.

```
$ ./append_last.awk file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv > newfile.tsv
```

If your files are large, `awk` will be *orders of magnitude* faster than spawning multiple subshells to do the same job. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste -d' ' file[1-3] |
   awk '{printf "%s %s ", $1, $2; for(i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "%s ", $i; print ""}' | 
   column -t
A1  B1  1  5  0
A2  B2  9  8  1
A3  B3  8  4  7

$ paste -d' ' file[1-3] | 
   awk '{printf "%s\t%s", $1,$2; for(i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "\t%s", $i; print ""}'
A1      B1      1       5       0
A2      B2      9       8       1
A3      B3      8       4       7
```